# Does and where to does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m} \prod_k \frac{1}{\lambda_{k,m}!}$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, integer-partitions, constants

Given $n$ you get a number of partitions of $n$ and let's denote $\lambda_{k,m}$ to be the $k$th part of the $m$th partition. Now I built the following sum, that stimulated the following question:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m} \prod_k \dfrac{1}{\lambda_{k,m}!}\overset{?}{=}2.5294773\dots
$$

(I calculated till $n=50$, tbc...).

> Does this sum converge? How to prove that? If so, does the constant have a name?

I asked [ISC](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=2.5294773&lookup_type=simple) and a [SearchEngine](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q="2.5294773"+partition&oq="2.5294773"+partition&gs_l=hp.3...1566.1566.0.2531.2.2.0.0.0.0.560.560.5-1.1.0.msedr...0...1c.1.60.hp..2.0.0.0.s_AFcptPFB8) without success.

Comment: Looks like the number conveges to $$\prod_{k=2}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{k!}\right)^{-1} \approx 2.529477472079152648180116154253954242\ldots$$
No idea what this number is.

Comment: @achillehui really? I've got the feeling that your product overshoots my sum?

Comment: It should. This is what I get for your sum at various $n$
$$\begin{array}{r:l}
n & \text{sum}\\
\hline
25  & 2.528946417657449\\
50  & 2.529477390023793\\
75  & 2.529477472063312\\
100 & 2.52947747207915
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $n > 0$, let

- $p(n)$ be corresponding number of partitions.
- $q(n)$ be the corresponding sum $\displaystyle\;\sum_m \prod_k \frac{1}{\lambda_{k,m}!}$.

Recall $p(n)$ is the number of solutions for $(x_1, x_2, x_3 \ldots ) \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ of the equation:

$$x_1 \cdot 1 + x_2 \cdot 2 + x_3 \cdot 3 + \ldots = n$$

and its generating function is given by

$$\begin{align}
P(t)\; &\stackrel{def}{=} 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) t^n\\
&= (1 + t + t^2 + \cdots ) (1 + t^2 + t^4 + \cdots )(1 + t^3 + t^6 + \cdots )\cdots\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1-t^k \right)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
To construct the generating function for $q(n)$, we need to associate a factor
$\frac{1}{k!}$ to each part of a partition of $n$ with length $k$. This means

$$
\begin{align}
Q(t)\; &\stackrel{def}{=}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty q(n) t^n\\
&= \left(1 + \frac{t}{1!} + \left(\frac{t}{1!}\right)^2 + \cdots \right)
   \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \left(\frac{t^2}{2!}\right)^2 + \cdots \right)
   \cdots\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Consider following function:
$$g_2(t) \stackrel{def}{=} \prod_{k=2}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)$$

Since $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} = e^t - 1 - t\;$ has infinite radius of convergence, the infinite product on RHS defines an entire function over $\mathbb{C}$. The zeros of $g_2(t)$ are located on the circles $|t| = ( k! )^{1/k}, k = 2, 3, \ldots$. The one nearest to $0$ has radius $\sqrt{2}$. This implies $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{g_2(t)}$ is analytic for $|t| < \sqrt{2}$.

Notice we can express $Q(t)$ in terms of $g_2(t)$.

$$Q(t) = \frac{1}{(1-t)g_2(t)} = \frac{1}{(1-t)g_2(1)} + \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\frac{1}{g_2(t)} - \frac{1}{g_2(1)}\right)$$

and the last term in RHS is analytic for $|t| < \sqrt{2}$. If we pick a $r_2 \in (1,\sqrt{2})$ and Taylor expand the last term at $t = 0$:
$$\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\frac{1}{g_2(t)} - \frac{1}{g_2(1)}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n t^n$$
We will have $\alpha_n = o(r_2^{-n})$. As a result, we find

$$q(n) = \frac{1}{g_2(1)} + o(r_2^{-n})\quad\implies\quad
\lim_{n\to\infty} q(n) = \frac{1}{g_2(1)} = \prod_{k=2}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{k!}\right)^{-1}$$

As mentioned in comment, the limit
$$\frac{1}{g_2(1)} \approx 2.529477472079152648180116154253954242\ldots$$
and I have no idea what other meanings it carries.

Despite this, we can do a little bit better than just deriving the limit.
For any $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, let 
$$g_m(t) = \prod_{k=m}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)$$
It is entire on $\mathbb{C}$ with zeros lying on the circles $|t| = (k!)^{1/k}$ for integer $k \ge m$. In particular,

$$Q(t) = \frac{1}{g_1(t)} = \frac{1}{(1-t)g_2(t)} = \frac{1}{(1-t)\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t}}\right)g_3(t)}$$
has three simple poles $1, \pm \sqrt{2}$ for $|t| < \sqrt[3]{6}$.
If we separate these poles from $Q(t)$, we find:

$$Q(t) = \frac{1}{g_2(1)}\frac{1}{1-t} 
- \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2g_3(\sqrt{2})}\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}} 
+ \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2g_3(-\sqrt{2})}\frac{1}{1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}} 
+ \Delta_Q(t)
$$
where $\Delta_Q(t)$ is something analytic for $|t| < \sqrt[3]{6}$.

Pick any $r_3 \in (\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{6})$. Above separation leads to
following estimation for $q(n)$:
$$\begin{align}q(n) 
&= \frac{1}{g_2(1)} + \left( 
- \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2g_3(\sqrt{2})} 
+ (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2g_3(-\sqrt{2})}\right) 2^{-n/2} + o(r_3^{-n})\\
&\approx 2.5294774720791526481 + \left[\begin{array}{c} -2.9161303884150758204 \\ + (-1)^n 0.1628043195679213429\end{array} \right] 2^{-n/2}
\end{align}
$$
The table below compares the exact values of $q(n)$ with this approximation (upto 20 decimal places) for various $n$:

$$\begin{array}{r:l}
n & q_{exact}(n) & q_{approx}(n)\\
\hline 
25  & 2.52894\color{grey}{64176574489192} & 2.52894\color{grey}{59448304110955}\\
50  & 2.529477390023\color{grey}{7933300} & 2.529477390023\color{grey}{6415059}\\
75  & 2.529477472063311901\color{grey}{8} & 2.529477472063311901\color{grey}{7}\\ 
100 & 2.5294774720791502027 & 2.5294774720791502027
\end{array}$$
As one can see, this is a pretty decent approximation. When $n = 50$, it gives a number
accurate to $12$ decimal places.